# modal dialog not dismissing bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following modal dialog in a django tempalate

search_results.html

```
<div class="modal fade " id="search-results" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>Search Results:</h3>
                <h5>Click on a customer to go to customer's file</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6">Patients found {{customers.count}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Middle Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Phone No</th>
                            <th>Date of Birth</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {%for customer in customers %}
                            <tr onClick="parent.location='{% url 'customer-edit' id=customer.id%}'">    
                                <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                                <td>{{customer.first_name}}</td>
                                <td>{%if customer.middle_name%}{{customer.middle_name}}{%endif%}</td>
                                <td>{{customer.last_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{customer.telephone}}</td>
                                <td>{%if customer.birth_date%}{{customer.birth_date}}{%endif%}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {%empty%}
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6"><p class="text-center">No Patients Found</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="cancel" data-dismiss = "modal" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!--modal-content-->
    </div><!--modal-dialog-->
</div>
```

and a view that renders this template

In my webpage, i use ajax to post data of a search form and the view returns the html. I then append the model dialog on the page, and display the results.

ajax call

```
var form = $(".search-patient");
$(".search-patient").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'/customer/',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:form.serialize(),
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR){
            if ($("#search-results").length > 0){
                $("#search-results").remove();
            }//remove it if it was already there from previous search(Not the best way i know)

            $('body').append(data);
            $("#search-results").modal('show');
        }

    });
});
```

The problem is that while it shows the modal box ok, it won't let me dissmiss either by using the x or the Close button. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$("#search-results").modal('hide');` should do it.

```
$('.close').click(function(){
     $("#search-results").modal('hide');
});
```

Update:

```
var loading_dialog = $('#search-results');
loading_dialog.modal('show');

 loading_dialog.modal('hide');
```

Update:
  give `class="modal hide fade"`

```
<div class="modal fade " id="search-results" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
```

Replace With

```
<div class="modal hide fade " id="search-results" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: I think it must be $(".close").on(click, function) because the modal doesn't exist on page when code is executed correct? But still didn't work. I tried the same thing from browser's console still the same

Comment: Try to see the errors in console or give the alert box in close on click, I think it is not triggering.

Comment: still not working...no errors...:(. Not even with your update.The show method is working, the hide is not...

Comment: @Apostolos try without show like `$("#search-results").modal();`

Comment: I tried the following: Changed the ('body').append(data) to $('body').append("Some text") and it appends it twice, like form is posted twice. It is posted twice, I can't seem to know why

Comment: Where shall i change the class on the template or via javascript on the success function?

Comment: top of search_results.html `<div class="modal fade " id="search-results" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">`  `class="modal fade "` replace wit `class="modal hide fade"`